# How to determine nav-items to get full required width automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to make a header navbar. Here is my code:

```
<div class="has-navbar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active bg-warning first-item m-1">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> E-learning products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-newspaper"></i> Articles</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-1">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Events</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the menu `nav-item` **E-learning Products** does not have enough space to place correctly in the place of nav-item.

However the other `nav-item`s has extra space (as I mentioned out in the image).

So I need to make sure that every `nav-item` has enough required space based on the length of `<a>` links of `nav-items`.

And here comes the CSS code of this navbar:

```
/* Navbar */

        .has-navbar{
            margin-top:-10px;
            width:100%;
            height:30px;
        }

        .navbar{
            background-color: #fff !important;
            height:100%;
        }

        .nav-item{
            height:30px;
            width:130px !important;
        }

        .nav-item a{
            font-size:13px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .first-item{
            margin-right:-50px !important;
        }
```

So here I tried setting `width:130px !important;` for `.nav-item` and it didn't work out well. I also tried `width:100%;` and this is the result:

[image: captur2]

So how can I properly place each `nav-item` menu link properly in their required space so the menu links does NOT have **extra space** AND **not enough space**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you can do is set its `width` to `max-content`, which will be the maximum width that the content contained within can be.

Before(with `width: 130px !important;`):

[image: Before]

After(with `width: max-content;`):

[image: After]

```
.nav-item{
   height:30px;
   //width:130px !important;
   width: max-content;
}
```

**Note: If you think it's too short, you could set a `min-width` value to whatever you like.**